# The rotate button keeps on rotating when app resumed, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I am building a webapp for my website, i have a rotation icon to refresh the page but as soon as we resume the app after going to other app, the rotate icon starts to rotate like slowly slowly i dont know why, i checked the logs and all looks fine.

here is the code

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //define the variables here
    val weburl = "https://techdecipher.com/"
    lateinit var backhomebuttom: Button
    lateinit var scrollToTopButton: Button
    lateinit var scrollToBottomButton: Button
    lateinit var webView: WebView
    lateinit var refreshButton: Button
    private var isRefreshing = false
    val TAG = "Main Activity"


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ")

        // assign the id to each button
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        backhomebuttom = findViewById(R.id.backhomebuttom)
        scrollToTopButton = findViewById(R.id.scrollToTopButton)
        scrollToBottomButton = findViewById(R.id.scrollToBottomButton)
        refreshButton = findViewById(R.id.refreshButton)

       // network check
       // networkcheck()
        //call loadwebrulfunction
        loadweburlfunction()

        // reload button is clicked
        refreshButton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: reload")
            if (!isRefreshing) {
                // Start the rotate animation
                val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
                    0f, 360f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
                )
                rotateAnimation.duration = 500
                rotateAnimation.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
                rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
                refreshButton.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
                isRefreshing = true

                // Reload the website
                webView.reload()

                // Stop the animation after 3 seconds
                Handler().postDelayed({
                    refreshButton.clearAnimation()
                    isRefreshing = false
                }, 1000)
            }
        }

    }
 // load web url function on webview

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
   private fun loadweburlfunction() {
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl(weburl)

    }
      override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Stop the animation if it is running
        if (isRefreshing) {
            refreshButton.clearAnimation()
            isRefreshing = false
        }
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestart: ")
        refreshButton.clearAnimation()
        isRefreshing = false
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ")
    }

    //smooth scroll function

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ")
    }
}
```

the XML code is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Relative layout for making the buttons visible in swiperefreshlayout -->



        <!-- WebView to display content -->
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonContainer" />

        <!-- Button Container at the bottom -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <!-- Refresh Button -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/refresh_icon"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/rotate_to_refres" />

            <!-- Home Button -->

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/backhomebuttom"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/homepage"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_selector"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="0dp" />


            <!-- Top Button -->
            <Button
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollToTopButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/scrollup"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
            <!-- Bottom Button -->
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollToBottomButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/scrolldown"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <!-- Share Button -->
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/share"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[here is the screenshot the rotate icon rotates keeps rotating as soon as activity is resumed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TOjX.jpg)

Comment: You have give animation ```Animation.INFINITE``` that's why it is rotating

Comment: I have gone with

  rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Animation.ZORDER_NORMAL

however no change